# Google shows node links instead of Custom URL

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have got a serious problem. My drupal website was going well. All Links crawled and indexed by Google were custom(natural), But some days ago my website went down because of bandwidth problem. After then, all my links in Google started appearing in /node/number form. e.g I had a link like http://www.myexamplee.com/all-good and now its appearing as http://www.myexamplee.com/node/234 . Can any body help? (I have done autopath tricks, robot.txt node exclusion and clean url like stuff but did not get any results in one week of time). Any expert any paid service any idea will be welcomed.
Many thanks to all readers and experts.

Comment: Why Pathauto is not enough! http://preprocess.me/why-pathauto-is-not-enough.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how google got to index the node/123 URLs. Do you use a sitemap?
I would install the [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module to make sure those URLs get redirected to the SEO optimized URLs.
Select the "canonical" tag option in the config for that module.

I wouldn't worry to much about the SEO impact, especially if it's a new site.

Comment: There's a really great module called SEO Checklist that gives you a list of modules to install and configuration options. It includes Global Redirect. http://drupal.org/project/seo_checklist